# How to replace a UIImage in an array of structs?

Tags: arrays, swift, struct, uiimage

I created the following struct:

```
struct claimData {
    var images = UIImage()
    var imageTitle = String()
    var relatedUnrelated = String()
}
```

I made an array of this struct:

```
var reviewTableViewData = [claimData]()
```

I then pass this data to another view controller once the user presses a button. I pass it by creating another struct array, called ***secondTableViewData***, in the second view controller, and assign the value of ***reviewTableViewData*** (from the first view controller) to ***secondTableViewData*** (in the second view controller). The information successfully copies to the new array and displays correctly on my table view (located in the second view controller). The issue comes when I try to replace "***images***" (in the ***claimData*** struct) with a NEW image. I can successfully add an image, I can delete an image, I can even change the image title (***imageTitle***) successfully, but for some reason I can't replace the image itself. When I attempt to replace the image, the app crashes upon clicking "Use Photo" in the camera. I don't understand why it will let me replace the other items in the struct successfully, but it won't let me replace a UIImage. Please help and explain your answers... I'm still learning.

Here's the code that tells it to replace the photo:
Note: I created a variable called ***indexVar*** and assigned it to the *indexPath* that is selected in the table view's *didSelectRowAt*.

```
secondTableViewData[indexVar].images = (info[.originalImage] as? UIImage)!
```

I even tried assigning a completely NEW struct to the index in the array, and when I click "Use Photo" in the camera, it still crashes.

Thanks for your help!

Comment: Are you expecting to store several images within the 'images' variable? Or just 1? If several, should each image have its own title?

Comment: Also, what is relatedUnrelated? Is this a yes/no type response?

Comment: what error do you get when it crashes?

Comment: I don't get an error, the whole app just completely freezes and won't do anything. "Images" is actually supposed to be singular... it only holds one image per struct in the array. So in other words, each struct in the array has one image in "images." relatedUnrelated is simply a string variable that I either assign the word "Related" or "Unrelated" to, depending on what the user taps.

Comment: Essentially I'm just trying to replace the UIImage in the "images" variable stored at whatever index of the array the user selects. For some reason it won't let me assign the "images" variable to a new UIImage once one has already been stored in it.

Comment: @Joby I'm noticing an error after all. I'm receiving the following error: 'secondTableViewData.insert(claimData(images: (info[.originalImage] as? UIImage)!, imageTitle: picTakenOf, relatedUnrelated: "Related"), at: indexVar)'

Comment: in the plist have you allowed access to the photos?

Comment: @Joby yes I have

Comment: I found the issue... I forgot to dismiss the camera LOL! *facepalm* Thanks anyway.